# Magento changes to .php file not reflecting

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I made some changes to the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php`. However those changes are not reflecting in `includes/src/__checkout.php` in the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Observer` class.(After flushing all the magento caches)

In fact, I put some obvious errors in the `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Observer.php` file (removed the closing bracket of the class), still did not get any error anywhere from the website.

Why is magento ignoring changes I make to a php file?

Comment: First rule of Magento development, turn off **ALL** Magento Caches and Compiler, Full Page Cache if you have it. Nothing changes till the cached code and compiled code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all as you know, never change the core files.

You should disable compilation to fix that.

Via Magento admin. Navigate to `System > Tools > Compilation` page and click on `Disable` button.

Comment: I was just checking my understanding of things by modifying the files. When I need  to add something real, I will defnitely add my own Model/Observer files. Thanks a lot :)